Is it possible to create constexpr value of std::array inside std::array?
I'm working on optimization of some settings code. This is a large array of predefined values groupped in three nested structures. It is defined as
struct PerId
{
    const Id m_Id;
    const uint32_t m_Flags;
};

struct PerSeverity
{
    const Severity m_Severity;
    const std::vector<PerId> m_PerId;
};

struct PerTask
{
    const Task m_Task;
    const std::vector<PerSeverity> m_PerSeverity;
};
static const std::array rawSettingsPerTask
{
    PerTask{
        eTASK1,
        {{Severity::Critical, {{Violated, 0x22}, {Expired, 0x33}}},
         {Severity::Error, {{CantBeExecuted, 0x44}}}},
    },
    PerTask{
            eTASK2,{....}
    },
};

And I want to make this settings definition compile time. I made constexpr constructors to struct and moved from std::vector to std::array and now I have compilation issues, because of different template parameters:
template<std::size_t N>
struct PerSeverity
{
    constexpr PerSeverity(Severity severity, const std::array<PerId, N>& perId)
        : m_Severity(severity)
        , m_PerId(perId)
    {}

    const Severity m_Severity;
    const std::array<PerId, N> m_PerId;
};

template<std::size_t N, size_t M>
struct PerTask
{
    constexpr PerTask(enTaskID component, const std::array<PerSeverity<M>, N>& perSeverity)
        : m_Component(component)
        , m_PerSeverity(perSeverity)
    {}

    const enTaskID m_Component;
    const std::array<PerSeverity<M>, N> m_PerSeverity;
};
constexpr std::array rawSettingsPerComponent
{
    PerComponent<1,2>{
        eTASK1, { PerSeverity<2>{Critical, { PerId{Violated, 0x22},
                                             PerId{Expired, 0x33}}}}
    },
    PerComponent<2,2>{
        eTASK2 , { PerSeverity<2>{ Critical, { PerId{Violated, 0x11},
                                               PerId{Expired, 0x22}}},
                   PerSeverity<1>{ Informational, { PerId{Violated, 0x44}}}}
    }
}

So is it possible at all? May be I need some trick, but I can't find some thing similar.
Full example here

Kindly provide a [mcve]

@user12002570  Attached

You can't put a PerSeverity<1> in a PerComponent<2,2>, nor can you mix PerComponent<1,2> and PerComponent<2,2> in a std::array

You might be able to use tuples. Or even store initializer lists directly.

@Wutz Tuples will work (there's already an answer using them), but a heterogeneous {initializer-list} exists only in syntax and doesn't have an actual type.

@aschepler Note that the tuple answer was written after my comment. And for the initializer_lists; the idea was more that this could avoid templated structs altogether, so it could be homogenous. If PerSeverity stores an initializer_list<PerId> and PerTask stores an initializer_list<PerSeverity>, then it should work at compile time with no heterogenous storage required. Not sure if this actually works though.

I've decided to flesh out my idea to use initializer_list for compile-time storage of settings. Here it is on godbolt, here are the most relevant parts:

struct PerId
{
    const Id m_Id;
    const uint32_t m_Flags;
};

struct PerSeverity
{
    const Severity m_Severity;
    const std::initializer_list<PerId> m_PerId;
};

struct PerTask
{
    const Task m_Task;
    const std::initializer_list<PerSeverity> m_PerSeverity;
};
static constinit std::initializer_list<PerTask> rawSettingsPerTask
{
    PerTask{
        1,
        {{Severity::Critical, {{Violated, 0x22}, {Expired, 0x33}}},
         {Severity::Error, {{CantBeExecuted, 0x44}}}},
    },
    // PerTask{
    //         2,{....}
    // },
};

Apparently, initializer_list has been constexpr since C++14, so this should hopefully be usable for you.

You can't put a PerSeverity<1> in a PerTask<2,2>, nor can you mix PerTask<1,2> and PerTask<2,2> in a std::array.
Instead of std::array, you could use std::tuple, but that would make it harder on consumers of rawSettingsPerComponent.
template<std::size_t N>
struct PerSeverity
{
    constexpr PerSeverity(Severity severity, const std::array<PerId, N>& perId)
        : m_Severity(severity)
        , m_PerId(perId)
    {}

    const Severity m_Severity;
    const std::array<PerId, N> m_PerId;
};

template<typename... Severities>
struct PerTask
{
    constexpr PerTask(enTaskID component, const std::tuple<Severities...>& perSeverity)
        : m_Component(component)
        , m_PerSeverity(perSeverity)
    {}

    const enTaskID m_Component;
    const std::tuple<Severities...> m_PerSeverity;
};

constexpr std::tuple rawSettingsPerComponent
{
    PerTask{
        eTASK1, std::tuple{ PerSeverity<2>{Critical, { PerId{Violated, 0x22},
                                                       PerId{Expired, 0x33}}}}
    },
    PerTask{
        eTASK2 , std::tuple{ PerSeverity<2>{ Critical, { PerId{Violated, 0x11},
                                                         PerId{Expired, 0x22}}},
                             PerSeverity<1>{ Informational, { PerId{Violated, 0x44}}}}
    }
};


Correct me if I am wrong. But isn't std::tuple constexpr since C++20 only? The OP wants a solution for C++17. So I guess they would need to stick with std::variant, right?

@UniversE no, std::tuple::tuple( const Types&... args ); and the rvalue equivalent are constexpr since C++14

No, it is not (kind of). For an array, you need both fixed size (=number of elements) for the array and a fixed size for the elements.
This (and some more properties) are enforced by the type of the elements. Theoretically, it is possible to store elements of different type but same size in the same array. To do that in C++, it needs some more code.
You could try, for example, to use a std::variant as the element type. It guarantees the same size (using the maximum needed size of all types the variant supports - possibly wasting a lot of memory) and the same type for all elements.
Personal note, if you allow:
I strongly recommend to evaluate the benefits of all that, before implementing it, since accessing such array would always require to determine the exact type of the stored variant before you can use the value. It looks like you are over-engineering the solution.
